# Loop in teradata

Tags: sql, loops, teradata

I've tried googling but I just end up in pages about BTEQ so:

How do you create a simple loop in teradata? Can I do this?

Say that I want to query everything from 20 different tables that are named dw_table1, dw_table2, dw_table3, dw_table4, dw_table5 /.../ dw_table20 to send export the output to excel (by using the export option in teradata, so forgo that). I.e. I want to (with a mix of matlab syntax)

```
for i = 1:20           
    SELECT * FROM dw_table(i)
end
```

Where i = 1:20 is the range of the loop and dw_table(i) is the specific i. So it would query * from table1 and then more to table2 and continue until table20.

Or, lets assume that I want to do the same query as above but with a where condition that includes a loop in itself. This would then for table1 firstly send the query for column2 between 1000 to 2000, then for 2000 to 3000, then for 3000 to 4000 and so on. When it completes 9000 to 10000 the inner loop stops and the outer loop changes to to table2 and the process of the inner loop repeats. This continues for all 20 tables and for all the intervals.

```
for i = 1:20
    for j = 1:1000:10000
        SELECT * FROM dw_table(i)
        Where column2 between j and j+1000
    end
end
```

Where j controls the interval on column2
Thanks

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) what exactly you intend to do. Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I take it you're not into matlab, so sure...

Comment: Well, you are asking a SQL question. Don't expect SQL people to know Matlab

Comment: I agree with you. I tried to explain what I'm after in the text.

Comment: You could dp loops like this in a Stored Procedure, but then you can't export individual files. If you know how to do it in Matlab why don't you run this in Matlab?

Comment: I guess I have to take a look at stored procedures then... I do not have access to Matlab where I have access to the datawherehouse. So, I can't.

Comment: SQL is not a programming language.  You could use your scripting language of choice to manipulate the dynamic parts of your query - the table, and your i and j variables.  Within the query, you can use row_number to generate a counter handle your `between j and j + 1000`.

Comment: It may be possible to do this in a stored procedure with dynamic SQL execution to loop through object names that are predictably named. It may be more appropriate to handle this looping structure outside the database and simply call a stored procedure with the parameters for table name and column name that you wish to execute dynamically.